# How can i loop this

Tags: java, android, loops, tabs, swipe

How can I loop this  it can be any loop?

```
ActionBar.Tab tab1 = mActionBar.newTab();
tab1.setText("Tab 1");
tab1.setTabListener(this);

ActionBar.Tab tab2 =  mActionBar.newTab();
tab2.setText("Tab 2");
tab2.setTabListener(this);

//so that i cannot repeat the code again and again
//enhance for loop/ while /for

ActionBar.Tab tab3 = mActionBar.newTab();
tab3.setText("Tab 3");
tab3.setTabListener(this);

//i have declare three taps for swipe app 

mActionBar.addTab(tab1);
mActionBar.addTab(tab2);
mActionBar.addTab(tab3);
```

I am beginner in Java and android studio their is Java object that's why I cannot loop it

Comment: I dont know why people are downvoting this question. Clearly the OP is new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = mActionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Tab " + i);
    tab1.setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ?

```
    for(int i = 0; i<numberOfRepeat; i++){
        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = mActionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab " + String.valueOf(i));
        tab1.setTabListener(this);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab1);
    }
```

Comment: tab1.setText("Tab " + String.valueOf(i+1));

Answer (score 0):

```
int total=3;
ActionBar.Tab tab[]=new ActionBar.Tab[total];

for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
    tab[i]=mActionBar.newTab();
    tab[i].setText("Tab " + String.valueOf(i+1));
    tab[i].setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab[i]);
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. To help others, please include a brief explanation of how/why the above helps solve the problem. [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15433211).

Comment: @Leigh Code is quite simple so I don't think so there is a need of any explanation.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but keep in mind not everyone reading this will have the same skill level as you do. Adding a brief explanation makes the answer more useful -  to a broader range of users - in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

here is an endless loop:

```
boolean i = true;
while(i==true){
//doing
     }
```